# При присваивании значения слайдера выдает ошибку

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь присвоить slider'у значение, выдает ошибку

дело в том что все запускается, и работает но ошибка выдается, даже если это обычный Text

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
fuel.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/_MyScripts/fuel.cs:20)"

```
Slider fuels;
float carfuel;

fuels.value = carfuel; // тут ошибка
```

В первый раз сталкиваюсь, что делать?

полный код скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class fuel : MonoBehaviour {

public float carfuel = 40;
public bool isCharging = false;
public Slider fuels;
public GameObject fuelEmpityMenu;

private void Start() {
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}

void FixedUpdate () {

    if (!isCharging){
        carfuel -= Time.deltaTime;

    }
    if(isCharging){
        Debug.Log("car charging");
        carfuel = 40;
    }

    fuels.value = carfuel;

    if(carfuel <= 0){
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        fuelEmpityMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас `fuels` не инициализирована. По умолчанию `null`. Было бы странно, если бы ошибки не было.

Comment: @Suvitruf это как не инициализирована? В игре значение меняется, но ошибка все равно выдается

Comment: Ваша ошибка ничего общего с кодом приведённым не имеет. В вашем коде `fuels`. В ошибке `fuel`. Покажите необходимый код и 20 строку вашего **fuel.cs**

Comment: @Suvitruf все выложил

Comment: Где вы присваиваете значение `fuels`?

Comment: @Suvitruf public Slider fuels; 8 cтрока

Comment: Это объявление. По умолчанию там `null`.

Comment: @Suvitruf а как правильней инициализировать? на 2017.1.2f я так и инициализировал, все работало...

Comment: Тут всё зависит от того, как вы этот скрипт используете. Я так понимаю, вы в редакторе скрипт накидываете куда-то, а потом в поле слайдера накидывать какой-то объект. Так?

Comment: @Suvitruf да, это так

Comment: Т.е. изначально оно работает, но в какой-то момент там ошибка вылетает? Если да, то значит компонент слайдера был уничтожен. Если это так, попробуйте в `Awake` слайдера вызвать `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);`

Comment: @Suvitruf да, запустил игру, и сразу пишется ошибка. а этот код в fuel.cs кидать? если да, то не работает

Comment: в слайдер если кадать, то тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` выпадает в том случае, если ссылка, по которой вы патаетесь обратиться не указывает на объект.
В вашем случае вы, видимо, забыли перетащить`Slider` в соответствующее ему в инспекторе поле скрипта.

Comment: нет, я его не забыл добавить. Дело в том, что когда игра запускается, все работает, но ошибки пишутся. Тоже самое и с Text

Comment: @GENKY, когда вы нажимаете на ошибку в консоли - в иерархии подсвечивается объект источника ошибки (если скрипт, в котором она произошла наследник MonoBehaiviour). Проверьте не находится ли у вас на сцене два экземпляра этого класса, у одного из которых ссылки на объект отсутствуют. ещё сверху в окне иерархии есть поле для ввода, если вписать туда "t: ИмяКласса", то оно покажет вам все объекты на сцене, на которых висит данный компонент